# In Mongo, how to return a doc where fieldA = fieldB?

Tags: mongodb, find

The query returns two documents:

> db.testData.find({x:5});
>   { "_id" : ObjectId("529680a82ac8f8a788401688"), "x" : 5, "y" : 20, "z" : "hi" }
>   { "_id" : ObjectId("529690982ac8f8a78840169e"), "x" : 5, "y" : 5, "z" : "address" }

How to specify the condition x=y to return the last document?

Comment: This has been asked and answered a number of times already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [$where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) (which is slow and does not use indexes)

Your query will look like this:

```
db.testData.find({
   x: 5,
   $where: "this.x == this.y"
});
```

Thinking for a second and looking at your query. If you know that x = 5, you can do this :-)

```
db.testData.find({x: 5, y : 5});
```

Comment: db.testData.find({ $where: "this.x == this.y" }); will give the right answer.

Comment: The solution from the duplicate which uses the aggregation framework is likely a much better solution than using $where.

Comment: Wow, 2 downvotes! This is amazing. This solution can use index on field x = 5, and then it will iterate through all the fields with where. It is easy to write and easy to understand. Solution which is marked as a duplicate is definitely much harder to understand.